# Simple pagination algorithm with range

Tags: javascript

```
function generatePageRange(currentPage, lastPage) {
    const delta = 2;

    const range = [];
    for (let i = Math.max(2, (currentPage - delta)); i <= Math.min((lastPage - 1), (currentPage + delta)); i += 1) {
        range.push(i);
    }

    if ((currentPage - delta) > 2) {
        range.unshift('...');
    }
    if ((currentPage + delta) < (lastPage - 1)) {
        range.push('...');
    }

    range.unshift(1);
    if (lastPage !== 1) range.push(lastPage);

    return range;
}
 console.log('Selected page ${i}:', generatePageRange(5, 10));
```

I have a total page and page range and current page.

Current Output
[1, "...", 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, "...", 10]

expected output

Total Page = 10, range = 5

page no. 1 => 1, 2, 3, ---, 10

page no. 2 => 1,2,3, ---, 10

page no. 3 => ---, 3,4,---,10

page no. 4 => ---, 4,5,---,10

page no. 10 => 1, --- , 8, 9,10

Comment: are you sure about the wanted output? the first page is missing in some parts.

Comment: yes, that time put dot dot, range should be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non dynamic approach, you could separate the resilt into three parts, where the different actual page creates different array.

```js
function getPagination(page, total) {
    if (page < 3) return [1, 2, 3, '...', total];
    if (page < total - 2) return ['...', page - 1, page, '...', total];
    return [1, '...', total - 2, total - 1, total];
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) console.log(i, ':', ...getPagination(i, 10));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```